# Why does Waze give a time estimate for this road trip two hours lower than Google Maps?

Tags: driving, timetables, google-maps

Google Maps: 13 hours, 5 minutes

[image: Directions from Washington State to Stanford University: 1364km]

Waze: 11 hours, 15 minutes

[image: Directions to Stanford University, 450 Serra Mall, Stanford, CA: 1366km]

Pretty much the same path. Screenshots taken at the time, and both programs consider the traffic information.

What accounts for such a time estimate difference? Knowing this will help my scheduling.

Comment: Do you have different settings in terms of car type, number of people on board or whatever info you can set which may affect the use of some lanes? I doubt that on such a route it would make that much of a difference, though.

Comment: @jcaron yes. I've kept the default configuration on both applications, and they seem to match.

Comment: Isn't the Waze estimate an obvious bug? To drive 1366km in 11:15, you need to keep an average speed of 75.5mph. Doesn't the involved states Washington, Oregon and California all have a maximum speed limit of 70mph?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo maybe they look at the speed people actually drive at?

Comment: This pretty much sums it up: https://mobile.twitter.com/tnose14/status/956301949921460225

Comment: @lambshaanxy sounds accurate :)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt At least Google does that, but I can't really believe that the average speed is so much above the allowed speed.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo that'd match the typical speed I'm witnessing. People typically do 80 on 70mph roads if no traffic. US roads confuse me.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Is your speedometer showing 80 or are you actually driving 80? In both cases, you will not reach an average speed of 75.5mph on such a long trip.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I won't pronounce myself on my personal respect for the US regulations but definitely 80mph is a typical speed on 70mph roads from my observation of the autochthons. 75 average over the trip could make sense it's >99% highway.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt It really depends on the state. Just match the speed of others, and know that the informal rules about what speed limits really mean change whenever you cross state borders.

Comment: In my experience (about 10 years of use), Waze tends to be shockingly accurate in its time predictions. Of course, for a longer drive like this, you will have to add in stop time - you're not going to make that whole trip on one tank of gas. When subtracting stop times, I've found that I'm pretty darn close to the Waze prediction, whether I'm commuting 50 miles to the office or driving 500+ miles across country. This does _not_ explain the difference between Waze and Google predictions, however, and YMMV.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo What cars display a speed you aren't actually driving at? 75 on the highways in this area seems totally plausible but obviously doesn't account for traffic, and time in the city

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- in fact, speedometers do add a bit of tolerance to ensure they always show at least the current speed, not less. The tolerance margin for this used to be higher, which is why speedometer and actual speed may differ noticeably on older cars. On more recent cars the difference is hardly noticeable any more.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Most cars. Almost without exepection, car speedometers measure the rotation of the driveshaft and calculate an estimated speed by assuming a preconfigured wheel diameter. Depending on tyre wear and air pressure, the wheel diameter is however not a fixed constant. Since in most legislations speedometeres are only allowed to show a higher speed than the car is actually going, but never a lower speed, they are usually calibrated for a new tyre with the highest reasonable air pressure, meaning that in most situations, you are driving a bit slower than the speedometer actually shows.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo - and having a GPS running shows that my 2018 vehicle speedometer indicates about 3 km/hr higher than the actual speed.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo But, like the point still holds that everyone on US highways is doing ~77-80 mph on an 70 mph highway, then. It's not like they were all going under the speed limit and Franck was way off.

Comment: If you disobey the law as a visitor, you can't use the excuse that some locals do the same. Do you really want to take that risk?

Comment: @lambshaanxy is spot on, Waze is very aggressive in their route planning even in other parts of the world, in Europe and the Middle East I have seen them routing through tiny and narrow streets just to save a fraction of a minute

Comment: @PeterMortensen the risk is not much more than a few hundred dollars in fines, and for many the benefit of arriving an hour and a half earlier would justify the risk.  Those who are risk averse can drive sightly slower than the fastest cars (photo enforcement of speed limits is still rare in the US) and they will still be well over the posted limit with almost no chance of being fined.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's simple.

Google Maps assumes that you are being a good driver and going no higher than the posted speed limit, and slower if necessary based on the speed of traffic.

> When you input your destination into Google Maps your original estimate is made based upon posted speed limits, current traffic conditions, and the distance between your starting point and destination.

*Source: https://www.verizonconnect.com/resources/article/google-maps-travel-time/*

Waze does not take into account the speed limit and only looks at the speed of traffic. U.S. drivers tend to drive 15-20 mph over the speed limit on expressways (source - personal experience), and Waze assumes you will drive the speed of traffic. Note that driving over the speed limit is (obviously) illegal, so break the law at your own peril - it's not Waze's fault if you get a speeding ticket.

Here's an [Medium article](https://medium.com/waze/under-the-hood-real-time-eta-and-how-waze-knows-youre-on-the-fastest-route-78d63c158b90) **written by Waze themselves** explaining how they compute travel time. Notice that the article does not mention speed limit as a factor.

I have taken long (4-5 hour) trips using Waze. I always drive the speed limit, which is often significantly slower than the speed of traffic, and I usually end up spending about 25% more time on the road than Waze predicts.

Comment: Google also makes the reverse mistake--assuming the speed limit on roads where it's not possible to actually drive at that speed on parts of it.  (The offender I noted was Titus Canyon Road.   I reported it as a problem as it should never direct someone down that road but they have not fixed it.  While the "limit" is 25 mph there are plenty of places on it that if you were driving 25 mph you would at best be in the hospital and more likely dead.)

Comment: Looks like some rules are a bit outdated out there, with regards to modern standards for cars and constructions.

Comment: @LorenPechtel You should make it clear by "actually driving 25 mph" you mean "and not slower".  I was wondering if there was a road that was constructed such that going as slow as the speed limit would be usually fatal.  :)

Comment: @Yakk I can't imagine a road where the only safe approach was to speed.  The road I'm referring to has a substantial chunk where it's one lane only (the entire road is one way), tight turns, if conditions were bad it would be 4x4 only and even in good times something like a sports car would probably end up high centered.

Comment: @Yakk During dust storms in the Phoenix area, driving under the speed limit is a serious risk and will get you pulled over

Comment: @forresthopkinsa did you really mean `under` the speed limit or is it a typo?

Comment: Actually, that may be bad/old advice. The Arizona DOT now recommends pulling completely off the road (past the emergency lane/shoulder and on to the desert itself), stop your car, turn on/activate your emergency brake, take your foot/feet off the brake pedal, and finally turn off all lights. The bit about turning off lights and feet off brake pedal, is a history of people following other people's tail- or brake-lights and not realizing the car in front has stopped.

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ I meant `under`, I was giving a rare example of needing to go above the speed limit.

Comment: @CGCampbell As far as I know, it's *both*. You're supposed to pull off the road, but if you're not off the road, you absolutely **must** drive at the normal speed of traffic. I heard this from a police officer who had actually pulled someone over for this. When visibility is reduced, people impeding the flow of traffic are more dangerous than people going 5mph over.

Comment: Another reason to push the makers for ADAS on every car (and regulators for making those obligatory). (Some) modern cars are equipped with a radar sensor that measures the safe distance and optionally applies emergency brakes when the driver fails to brake at the vehicle in front. Doesn't save repair money, but damn can save a lot of lives! And it's not just Teslas.

Answer (score 20):

Google Maps is "right" (only if no stops or traffic).  Waze is wrong.

I've driven that exact route (Seattle to/from Bay Area via I-5) a couple dozen times.  Only once did I manage 13 hours, and that was with only light traffic, literally no stops except for gas (2 brief stops), and consistently 5-10 MPH above the posted limit (which is what most of the rest of the cars were doing).

More typical is around 15-16 hours.  That gives time for stretch breaks, stops for food, and possible traffic in the Seattle, Portland, and SF metro areas.

Answer (score 1):

I have just noticed that Waze now has an option to personalize ETA based on past drives:

[image]

This may explain the difference with Google Maps. It's quite accurate at predicting my ETA in the US.

Answer (score 0):

An additional possible answer is Competition.

When a smartphone user uses Waze and another app, if they find Waze provides them with a marginally faster route, they'll presume that Waze has a better routing algorithm (at least for that route), and thus choose to use Waze for that route. And so Waze gets more usage hours and advertising revenue.

To achieve this marginally faster route, the Waze routing algorithm may use different metrics and may also apply a scaling to the result. Though there is no real way to verify this without taking a look at the source code...

Comment: Remember that Waze is owned by Google...

Comment: Aw shucks. Didn't know that.

Comment: I am downvoting this answer because the real competition is providing an exact ETA, not just a faster route that can't be achieved without jeopardizing other motorists' health. To achieve an exact ETA, an algorithm may take the driving history of the user into consideration, **for example**

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ Waze does have a "Personalize your ETA" option. Though, wouldn't say it makes my ETA 100% accurate. Not even sure how it works (for example, as a motorcyclist I can skip traffic on some roads but on others it's difficult or impossible so I can't skip traffic on others).